# Pageable not working with spring data aerospike

Tags: spring-data, aerospike

I am using aerospike spring data

```
compile 'com.aerospike:spring-data-aerospike:1.0.2.RELEASE'
compile 'com.aerospike:aerospike-client:3.3.4'
compile 'com.aerospike:aerospike-helper-java:1.2'
```

When am trying to work with pageable am getting all the records instead of just one page with the specific set of records

```
Page<Account> findByGender(String gender, Pageable pageable);
```

This method is listed under interface

```
public interface AccountRepo extends AerospikeRepository<Account, UUID>
```

And accessing it by passing Gender and pageable

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, pageSize);
```

Comment: If there's a bug or a feature missing you should open a new [issue](https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/issues) on the [aerospike/spring-data-aerospike](https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike) repo at GitHub.

Comment: I tried, but Jira link is broken on their github page, they have mention stackoverflow so I posted it out here as well

Comment: Follow this link: https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/issues/new  That should work.  GitHub has its own system for issues, it doesn't use JIRA.

Comment: My bad, I am adding it up there. The ReadMe pointed me to the JIRA Stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for directing me to this. Its indeed not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aerospike is a distributed database, which means that scans and queries are sent to all the nodes in the cluster. Each of the nodes is shared-nothing with the others, so they don't coordinate the order or records returned. Similarly, within the node scans and queries are multi-threaded operations spread across the cores. That's another reason why the order of the results is different each time.

The workaround for pagination is to cache the full set of results on the client-side, then move through them. In an RDBMS, memory is allocated on the server-side for sorting and caching the results. In a distributed RDBMS, a specific node needs to be designated, all the results moved from the other nodes to it, and there it must be buffered, sorted, and cached. The design philosophy of Aerospike is to not waste server resources in such a way, but to move the responsibility of that operation to the application side instead, leaving the server cluster to handle many requests at very low latency.

In your application you should buffer, sort, and cache the result, and paginate through this cache. You can actually cache these results back into Aerospike (for example into an in-memory namespace), with a limited TTL.

Piyush posted in Medium on this topic:
I wrote some Medium posts on how to sort results from a scan or query:

- [Sorted Results from a Secondary Index Query in Aerospike — Part I](https://medium.com/@pgupta/sorted-results-from-a-secondary-index-query-in-aerospike-9e05117a68ef)
- [Sorted Results from a Secondary Index Query — Part II](https://medium.com/@pgupta/sorted-results-from-a-secondary-index-query-part-ii-de17f43f7fec)

Comment: I understand sorting is something which I don't get out of this, but without pagination implemented on the server side is there a way to ensure that I am able to read all the records without doing a lookup on every read. Is there an option to read bulk records, because fetching so much data in the single call can be difficult

Comment: Yes, batch-reads do that. For the Java client that's an [AerospikeClient.get()](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html#get(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,%20com.aerospike.client.Key[])) with a list of keys.  And really, be aware that when an RDBMS does a scan it goes over all the rows as well.